# How to place textviews with large text on left and right?

Tags: android, textview

i am using two textviews to display total balance for this i am using two textviews the first textview has a large text string and second one will have amount that is also a large number. the problem is that when content loads the text of first string is under text of second string. how to fix this?
here is my code any help will be appreciated

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rlaout_balance_list_item"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:text="type"
            android:id="@+id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_type"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/balance_list_item"
            android:layout_weight="8"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_value"
            android:text="0.0"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/balance_list_cash"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/balance_list_item"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Relative layout instead of linear

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlaout_balance_list_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textColor="@color/balance_list_cash"
        android:textSize="@dimen/balance_list_item"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_value"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/balance_list_item"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you used exactly what is posted in answer? if so that should work.

Comment: My understanding from your question is "you need to show 2 text one beside other horizontally without over lapping text " is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You will never get the result as you want if you use a layout like this. Please change the `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"`

Otherwise try something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="TextViecxvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcvxbcxv
    bcxvbcxvvvvvvvvvvvbcxvbcxvbcxvbcxvbcvbcxvbcxvbcxvbcxvbcxvbnbm,vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvcbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbvw" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="cvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxvxb" />
```

Comment: but i want to put my textviews on left and right side of each other thats why i have used horizontal.

Comment: @User : did u get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlaout_balance_list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="type"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_balance_list_footer_item_value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```